# Tkinter button with Image has borders

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

**EDIT**

I am using pictures as buttons. The 3rd image is the "Start" button and the 4th image is the "Numpad" button.

The buttons take more space than the image does, as you can see in the first image. I would like to take away that space so only the image space is taken.

---

I would like to get rid of the space, that the borders take, because I want the buttons to only take the space of the image size.

First image has this line of code in the MainButton class:

```
self.configure(bg=color['background'], activebackground=color['background'], borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
```

Second image has this line of code in the MainButton class:

```
self.configure(bg=color['background'], activebackground=color['background'])
```

Full code:

```
class MainButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.helv20 = Font(root= self,family="Arial",size=18)
        self.helv18 = Font(root= self,family="Arial",size=16)   

        self.configure(bg=color['background'], activebackground=color['background'], borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)   
    def _active(self, event):
        self.configure(image=self.ActiveImage)

    def _inactive(self, event):
        self.configure(image=self.DefaultImage)

class RunButton(MainButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MainButton.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.bind("<ButtonPress>", self._active)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease>", self._inactive)

        self.DefaultImage=PhotoImage(file="img/mainbutton_green.png")
        self.ActiveImage=PhotoImage(file="img/mainbutton_active.png")   

        self.configure(image=self.DefaultImage, compound=CENTER, font=self.helv20)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You wrote "First image has this line of code in the MainButton class...borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0 ...". Does that code give you what you want? Also, your images seem reversed. The second image is what I would expect if you turned off the border and hightlightthickness. Also, what are the third (green rectangle) and forth (gray rectangle) images for? Finally, are these tkinter buttons or ttk buttons?

Comment: can't you use `width` and `height` to set button size ? You can try also `padx` and `pady`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Edited my post. The buttons take more space than they need to. The buttons are tkinter buttons.

Comment: I don't see any extra space in the second image, and when I run your code I don't see any extra space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`borderwidth=0` just remove the border (which give the impression of relief, so it has the same effect has doing `relief='flat'`), but does not reduce the space around the image. To do that, you can use the `padx` and `pady` options of the button:

```
self.configure(bg=color['background'], activebackground=color['background'], 
               borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, padx=0, pady=0)
```